# Arrays in the text

Tags: arrays

In my example below, I need to write it "nicely", i.e., to have the array with ones smaller, less space around,...Anyone knows how to do it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}


\newcommand{\vX}{\boldsymbol{X}}
\newcommand{\vP}{\boldsymbol{P}}
\newcommand{\vN}{\boldsymbol{N}}
\newcommand{\vT}{\boldsymbol{T}}
\newcommand{\vI}{\boldsymbol{I}}



\begin{equation}\nonumber
\vX_1 = -\rho\vP^{o}\vT-\rho\vP^g\big(\left(
\begin{array}{l}
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right)\otimes \vI\big)\vN,
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)`

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use the `smallmatrix` environment, which is provided by the `amsmath` package, encased in `big`-sized parentheses:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}

\newcommand{\vX}{\bm{X}}
\newcommand{\vP}{\bm{P}}
\newcommand{\vN}{\bm{N}}
\newcommand{\vT}{\bm{T}}
\newcommand{\vI}{\bm{I}}

\begin{document}
\[
\vX_1 = -\rho\vP^{o}\vT-\rho\vP^g\bigl(
        \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1\\1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
        \otimes \vI\bigr)\vN
\]
\end{document}
```

---

Addendum: If one leaves off the `\big` modifiers around the `smallmatrix`, one gets

[image]

You may, or may not, prefer this look to the one shown above.

Comment: Almost the same as mine, but: 1. the `\newcommand` lines should be before `\begin{document}` and 2. `\nonumber` should not be used, preferring `equation*`.

Comment: @egreg - good points, I'll make the changes.

Comment: Oh, and if you use `\left(` and `\right)` around the `smallmatrix`, the result will be even better (you can see it in my deleted answer).

Comment: @egreg - Thanks, implemented your follow-up suggestion as well. :-)